# Is it possible to update room title (and other options) using ejabberd REST API?

Tags: ejabberd

I am looking at Ejabberd's Admin API - https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/, there are APIs to

- create room
- create_room_with_opts
- destroy_room
- set_room_affiliations
- get_room_* (few get room APIs)

but there is no option to update room options. Is there any way to update room title and other options of an existing room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was right there :)

https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#change-room-option

Example usage:

```
$ ejabberdctl get_room_options room1 conference.localhost
title
public  true
moderated       true
...

$ ejabberdctl change_room_option room1 conference.localhost title ABCD
$ ejabberdctl change_room_option room1 conference.localhost moderated false
$ ejabberdctl change_room_option room1 conference.localhost public false

$ ejabberdctl get_room_options room1 conference.localhost
title   ABCD
public  false
moderated       false
...
```

Comment: Wow, I must be blind. I even asked a colleague to look into the list in case I am missing something, he didn't find anything either. We should both go and get our eyes tested now. :) Thanks!